# invalid use of type name or subtype name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to add values to a indey-by table:

```
DECLARE
TYPE index_by_table1 IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY 
PLS_INTEGER;

whilecount PLS_INTEGER;

BEGIN

whilecount:= 1;

WHILE whilecount <= 10
LOOP

index_by_table1(whilecount) := whilecount;
```

dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(index_by_table1(whilecount)));
whilecount:=whilecount + 1;

```
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I get an error message which says:
PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
and
no function with name 'INDEX_BY_TABLE1' exists in this scope

I am confused because I was told that index-by tables do not need to be initialized. But to me it seems like this error would occur when you are referring to an object which is not initialized, right? Please tell me what I am doing wrong or do not understand about index-by tables.

Comment: You are using a type, but you need an object of that type (an array which is an instance of that type). Index-by tables are associative arrays, by the way, often called map or dictionary in other programming languages. It is used to map two things, e.g. a country name with its country code. Do you need this, i.e. do both the index and the value have meanings? Most often you'd just use a simple array / list (`TYPE type_table_of_number IS TABLE OF NUMBER`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a type (`index_by_table1`), now use it for a variable declaration:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE index_by_table1 IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  v_array index_by_table1;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    v_array(i) := i;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: So i discovered that "index_by_table1 index_by_table_test;" works while "index_by_table1 index_by_table_test := index_by_table_test();" does not. Why's that? Initializing varray for example works this way.

Comment: Collections in PL/SQL are quite confusing. Associative arrays (`TYPE type_associative_array IS TABLE_OF NUMBER INDEX BY INTEGER`) look almost the same as mere lists (`TYPE type_list IS TABLE_OF NUMBER`), but they work very different from each other. The associative array is ready-to-use by mere declaration (`v_associative_array  type_associative_array;`), while the list needs a constructor and must be extended with every entry (`v_list type_list := type_list();` and `v_list.extend;`). Here is a good read on them: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-collections